# How to add new picture in xml tags of video-js.zencoder.com?

Tags: javascript, xml, video.js

I want to change the default poster of video.js to custom poster.

```
<Contents>
    <Key>oceans-clip.jpg</Key> 
    <LastModified>2012-02-10T18:12:39.000Z</LastModified>
    <ETag>"994f65e061d408d7147d5171c8931426"</ETag>
    <Size>68270</Size>
    <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
</Contents>
```

Instead I want to have:

```
<Contents>
    <Key>(own poster)</Key> 
    <LastModified>2012-02-10T18:12:39.000Z</LastModified>
    <ETag>"994f65e061d408d7147d5171c8931426"</ETag>
    <Size>68270</Size>
    <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
</Contents>
```

Where i can put the company poster if video.js does not play                     any videos

Comment: The title is not supposed to be the entire question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify your own poster when you create the `<video>` element.

```
<video id="your_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="YOUR_POSTER.png">
 <source src="my_video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```